# What is the price for a call to Google Place Near By Search api next results?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

Google Place Near By Search api returns up to 20 results in the first call can allow to call again the api with the next results token.
can anyone tell what is the price for calling the api with then next results token? is it included in the first call (and therefore free) or it costs the same as another new call? i cant find anything regarding it in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You should address this question to Google Maps Platform support team: https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Comment: Thanks, i did. once they will answer i will post the answer here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pricing not programming and should be asked to the customer support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting google here is the answer:
"Places API nearby search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. Note that each search counts as a single request against your usage limits.
To simply put, accessing additional results via the pagetoken parameter will incur another Places - Nearby Search request (0.032 USD per call)."

So bottom line is, calling the request to the get the next page results is being charged again. the price of the call is the same as the call to the first page results.